# Disable nuxt link based on boolean

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I can't seem to find a good way to disable a nuxt-link based on a data variable. Could anyone suggest something? I've tried looking at doucmentation but I can't come up with anything.

Say I have a boolean called `disable` I want to do something like this

`<nuxt-link :disabled="disable"></nuxt-link>`

I basically just don't want the link to be clickable if the boolean is set to false

Comment: Change `="disable"` to `="disabled"`

Comment: uh sorry my bad, my code does say disabled. I don't think nuxt-link supports this prop, but I just need help with a way to stop the link from being clickable if a boolean is false

Answer (score 35):

[`<nuxt-link>` is essentially `<router-link>` of Vue Router](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/).

For Nuxt2, you can disable a link using the [`event` prop](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#event).

Assuming your one of your `data` or `computed` property is `disabled` boolean:

```
<nuxt-link :event="disabled ? '' : 'click'"></nuxt-link>
```

## Working example:

```js
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const Baz = { template: '<div>baz</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar },
  { path: '/baz', component: Baz }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  data(){
    return {
      disabled: true
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.6.5/dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <div>
    <!-- Assume they are <nuxt-link> because they are the same -->
    <router-link
      :event="disabled ? '' : 'click'"
      to="/foo"
    >
      Go to Foo ({{ disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled' }})
    </router-link>&nbsp;
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>&nbsp;
    <router-link to="/baz">Go to Baz</router-link>
  </div><br />
  <button @click="disabled = !disabled">Toggle Foo availability</button><br /><br />
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I decided to just add a class based on the boolean because I didn't want the link to be clickable

Comment: do I prevent it from routing routing without closing the click event dynamically?

Comment: @vulkan what do you mean?

Comment: i did mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594886/blocking-of-going-router-without-closing-the-click-event-nuxt-js

Comment: Thanks! But actually, in vue-router v4, which current versions of nuxt are using, this prop is deprecated. Here is how to fix it: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link

Comment: @Fabian do you know how to translate `<nuxt-link :event="disabled ? '' : 'click'"></nuxt-link>` to v4 style? I'm struggling to understand how the previous event prop maps onto this new `v-slot` approach

Answer (score 12):

I found that the most simple way was to just create a class for the disabled links. I'm still not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works for me and does exactly what I want.

```html
<nuxt-link to="/search" :class="{ disabled: disabled }"> Search </nuxt-link>
```

my css

```css
.disabled {
   color: lightgrey
   pointer-events: none
}
```

Comment: It only disabled the link "visually". You can still click on it and it will take you to the `/search` route

Comment: you shouldn't be able to click on it with `pointer-events` set to none

Comment: @Sebj You can add an additional style being `pointer-events: none`, which will disable clicks on the element. Is it enough? Who knows.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do this, which I'd like the most. Is to change the tag to the `button` and use the native `:disabled` state.

```html
<nuxt-link tag="button" :disabled="disabled" to="/some/location">Some location</nuxt-link>
```

Then just turn the button into the link with the help of styles.

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks. Hey, @Samantha this should be the right answer.

Comment: It doesn't work if you use a link (`<a>`) instead of a button

Comment: @Sebj yes, you are right, cause `<a>` tag doesn't support `disabled` property

Answer (score 4):

In Nuxt3 this works for me: `:to="canNavigate ? link : null"`

Comment: Ok, this works in a way, however it results in an an empty `<a>` tag (no href), which _something_ out there may complain about (browser, HTML validators, etc)

Comment: It throws a warning
```[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "to". Expected String, Object, got Null ```

Answer (score 2):

In Vue Router 4, `router-link` do not support `tag` and `event` props anymore. [Here](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link) you can have more information.

I'll copy the example from the link above here:

```html
replace
<router-link to="/about" tag="span" event="dblclick">About Us</router-link>
with
<router-link to="/about" custom v-slot="{ navigate }">
  <span @click="navigate" @keypress.enter="navigate" role="link">About Us</span>
</router-link>
```

And I'll give a real example of usage. This piece of code I'm using in a real project, using nuxt and tailwind.

```html
<nuxt-link
  v-slot="{ navigate }"
  class="flex-grow font-ember"
  :to="`lesson/${l.lesson_id}`"
  append
  custom
>
  <button
    class="flex items-center"
    :class="{
      'text-gray-400 cursor-not-allowed': !l.released,
      'text-gray-900': l.released,
    }"
    :disabled="!l.released"
    @click="navigate"
  >
    ...
  </button>
</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `event` prop if you simply want to disable a nuxt-link

```
<nuxt-link event="">Go to Foo</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case anyway you can click on it. It displaying disabled but still clickable.
You need to use attribute `tag` in you `nuxt-link`

Example here `<nuxt-link tag="button" :disabled="disable"></nuxt-link>`

Answer (score 0):

None of these seemed to work for me, so I set the :to on the nuxt-link to a computed method. The to attribute on nuxt link will redirect nowhere when empty. For example:

```
<script>
export default{
    computed: {
        redirectRequest(){
            return this.isMobile ? "" : "/Worklog";
        }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <NuxtLink :to="redirectRequest"></NuxtLink>
</template>
```